# Having trouble getting two images to slide from left and right to center

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

Here's the link to the github with my code: https://github.com/jtylerm/website-issues

I'm building the site in reactJS. I tried animating the two images with CSS but it doesn't animate correctly. The two images slide in partially then "jump" to the center. The two images need to overlap, which is why I have a z-index listed in the CSS.

I'm not against animating the images using javascript, if that is a better solution than using CSS.

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use css3 for animations. use js to toggle classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the images need to end, but this is an example of how you can let them slide in smoothly.

To let the green image be on top, assign `z-index: -1` to the purple image.

```css
.from-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  animation: move-right 3s ease forwards;
}

.from-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  animation: move-left 3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes move-right {
  100% {
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes move-left {
  100% {
    right: calc(50% - 50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="from-left" src="http://placehold.it/100/00ff00">
  <img class="from-right" src="http://placehold.it/100/0000ff">
</div>
```

Comment: this is close. I need the two images to overlap each other completely in my case. when you look in the browser at the site I linked, you can see that I am trying to connect an image of an easel and an image of a monitor. the two actually meet with the code I linked. they just do it in an awful way

Comment: Thanks Gerard! This fixed my issue. I clicked accept answer on your response. Thanks again